# Creating File in other pc Connected to Lan using java

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to Create a txt file using java in other pc and i am trying to doing code is.

```
try {
            File f = new File("sftp://ip/home/username/krish.txt");

            boolean check = f.createNewFile();
            if (check) {
                System.out.println("File Created!!!");
                return true;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("File not Created!!!");
                return false;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

what i am getting error is :

```
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:959)
```

can any body suggest solution?

Comment: Are you sure Java support SFTP natively?  There appear to be several libraries available for this.

Comment: @MarkWagoner then can u tell me how to use this?

Answer (score 1):

To manage file that are in a remote machine you will use a network communication protocol. in your case  you are trying to use Secure FTP , so you have to use a Java API that handle this job . try [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)
 it may help you.

Comment: what should i do with that jar just include in lib? nothing else?

Comment: its little but complex logic. :(

Comment: try [Apache Camel FTP](http://camel.apache.org/ftp.html)  ,here is a simple [example](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/06/sftp-apache-commons-file-download.html)